# How should I handle a job change for a client as a provider?

Tags: software-industry, new-job, job-change, promotion, contractors

I'm quite in a situation where I don't know how to react properly.
I'm a provider from another company in a mission at my client's office and I've been here for a year and a half now.

Today my boss got back from 1-month vacation and during his leave I was asked to replace him temporarly as it is not my main job but as a Junior I thought it would be a good experience.

Also today the boss of my boss came in my room to tell me I'll do the job my boss used to do for my team.

I quite like this position of managing but this brings so much more responsability as I'm only a junior developper for a provider, I would gladly stay in this position if it was for a pay raise but it would require me to ask for my company's manager for a pay raise because the mission changed so they would notify the change to my client.

I'm not sure the client would keep me if the payment would increase.

Is it a proper way to ask for more money to my company without endangering this possible promotion ?

Comment: We could help you better if you tell us whether "boss" means the supervisor who works for your client, or the supervisor who works for the company that provides your services.  Who decides how much money *you* may take home?

Answer (score 3):

This should be between your company and the client. Inform your manager and let the 2 enter a dialogue over it. Your responsibility is not to discuss pay or anything else, just to do the assigned work.

If the request was in writing then forward it to whoever handles the client.

Answer (score 0):

Well done!  Sometime you need to change your handle: Junior Provider is no longer correct.

When you take on work with more responsibility, your client company should expect to pay your company more. Then, your company should pay you more.

1. the work is harder.
2. the consequences of mistakes on your part are higher.

Those things are worth real money.

If your client has asked you to take more responsibility, you should tell the people at your own company about that. If you can, provide them a description of your new work. Then they can approach your client about increasing the rate your client pays them.  And you should not be embarrassed to ask your own company for an increase for yourself.

Be patient, though. These changes sometimes take some time.